# Gulp and glob-stream task finishing too soon

Tags: gulp

I have a Gulp task that uses glob-stream to recursively loop through directories and files to perform a task, similar to below, but far more elaborate:

```
var gs = require('glob-stream');

var config = {
  PATH: 'some/path/*.*'
}


function doSomething(filePath) {
  var stream = gs.create(filePath);

  // Do something

  return gs.on('data', doSomething);
}


gulp.task('compile', function() {
  var filePath = config.PATH;
  return doSomething(filePath);
});
```

I can have the task achieve the results and compile what I need, but unfortunately Gulp believes the task has finished while it's still running, causing issues in my build process - How can I avoid this? I'm already using run-sequence but to no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you manually walking the directory tree with a recursive function? Why not just let `glob-stream` do the work for you? Then you only have to take care of the `//Do something` part:

```
var config = {
   PATH: 'some/path/**' //glob pattern for all subfolder and files
};

function doSomething(filePath) {
   //Do something
}

gulp.task('compile', function() {
  var stream = gs.create(config.PATH);
  stream.on('data', doSomething);
  return stream;
});

gulp.task('secondTask', function() {
  console.log('secondTask');
});

gulp.task('default', function() {
  runSequence('compile', 'secondTask');
});
```

The `some/path/**` glob pattern creates a stream of all folders and files below `some/path/`, so you don't have to implement the recursive tree walk yourself.

Note that the `compile` task returns the `stream`. Otherwise gulp can't tell when the `compile` task has completed and starts running `secondTask` before `compile` has finished.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response! The part I'm struggling with is the second task is still being called before the compile task completes, even after returning the stream!

Comment: Have you scrapped your recursive `doSomething()`? If yes, then you're probably doing something asynchronous in `doSomething()`. The stream finishes and your second task starts running, but your asynchronous operations haven't completed yet.